# Chatbot Can't click & enlarge image on MS Teams Application

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm having issues with MS Teams Chabot. We are using this for our company, and it is very essential to us. We can't click the image and enlarge it from our Chatbot. On web-based MS teams, it is working fine but on the MS Teams desktop client, it is not working. Here's the version of MS Teams installed on our workstation:
Microsoft Teams Version 1.4.00.26376 (64-bit)

Comment: It's known issue with recent update in Desktop Teams and must be fixed. It works sometimes and not working sometimes in desktop client.

Comment: Yes, It's a known bug. Teams is already working on it.